# How to pause/disable UILongPressGestureRecognizer on a UITableViewCell while in editmode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, long-press

In a tableview I have on every cell a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` which I add like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                          initWithTarget:self 
                                          action:@selector(TableCellLongPressed:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];
```

Now I do have the following problem I want the user to be able to rearrange the cell in the tableview so I have a button that sets the tableView to EditMode like this:

```
[self.myTableView setEditing:!self.myTableView.editing animated:YES];
```

Now when the user tries to drag a cell and does not drag it far enough the longPress fires his action which is very annoying for the user cause another view gets pushed.
How can I pause or disable the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` when the tableView is in EditMode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate delegate for this method:

gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:

In the method, check if you're editing the table and return NO if you are.

Tim

Comment: don't know how I could have overlook this method. thanks works great.